# Java soap client call syntax help wsdl provided

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

Given this wsdl

> https://betaservices.flhsmv.gov/ResidencyCheckService/ResidencyCheckService.svc?wsdl

I imported using wsimport. Setting up a call to the service like this:

```
        FLRESWebServiceService service= new FLRESWebServiceService();
        IFLRESWebService serv = service.getPort(IFLRESWebService.class);
        serv.wsVerifyFlResidency("userid", "pass1234", "someid", "01-01-1990");
```

Getting this error:

> Caused by: javax.xml.bind.MarshalException: Class "pkg_flres.WsVerifyFlResidency" is known to the JAXBContext but cannot be marshalled because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation

Did I call this service correctly?

Edit. Here's the class, it's clearly in there.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "wsVerifyFlResidency")
public class WsVerifyFlResidency {

@XmlElementRef(name = "i_UserId", namespace = "http://pkg_FLRES", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected JAXBElement<String> iUserId;
@XmlElementRef(name = "i_Password", namespace = "http://pkg_FLRES", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected JAXBElement<String> iPassword;
@XmlElementRef(name = "i_DlNumber", namespace = "http://pkg_FLRES", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected JAXBElement<String> iDlNumber;
@XmlElementRef(name = "dob", namespace = "http://pkg_FLRES", type = JAXBElement.class)
protected JAXBElement<String> dob;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You are calling the service correctly. The error is pretty clear though that the annotation is missing from the WsVerifyFlResidency. 
can you check if the below annotation is present in the class WsVerifyFlResidency.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "wsVerifyFlResidency")
```

if not try adding it.

Comment: I added part of that class to the question. Its definitely in there.